# Почему такое странное поведение объекта Date()?

Tags: дата, javascript

Для некоторых задач проекта мне нужно дату, вводимую пользователем, уменьшить на три часа, для получения GMT.

Делаю это так:

```
var GMTTimeShift=3;
var fdate=document.getElementById("fd1").value.split('-');
var d1=new Date();   
d1.setFullYear( fdate[2],parseInt(fdate[1])-1,fdate[0] );
d1.setHours(parseInt(document.getElementById("ft1").value), parseInt(document.getElementById("ft2").value));
parseInt(document.getElementById("ft2").value));
var a=d1.getTime()-GMTTimeShift*3600000;
d1.setTime(a);
console.log(d1);
```

Соответственно, есть три поля ввода, в которых прописывается время: часы минуты дата с дефисами, например
00 00 01-08-2012
Так вот.
При переходе с месяца на месяц, а именно 1 августа и 1 сентября отлавливаю странный глюк - мы получаем не 21 00 30-07-2012, а 21 00 30-11-2011 21:00
в остальные месяцы коррекция происходит верно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, причину такого поведения.

Comment: Попробуйте так отнимать время. Если будет та же проблема, то проблема не в этой части кода.    

    datestr= document.getElementById("ft1").value+":"+ document.getElementById("ft2").value+" "+ document.getElementById("fd1").value;
    d1=Date.parse(datestr);
    d1.setTime(d1.getTime()-GMTTimeShift*3600000);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Благодаря форуму [javascript.ru](http://javascript.ru) враг обнаружен и обезврежен!
а именно вот в этом месте:

```
d1.setFullYear( fdate[2],parseInt(fdate[1])-1,fdate[0] );
```

функция parseInt() имеет в себе второй, необязательный параметр, который отвечает за систему счисления при переводе. Без его указания функция сама решает, каково основание системы счисления, и конечно же, не угадывает, в результате чего получается такая бяка.
Правильный код в данном конкретном случае:

```
d1.setFullYear( fdate[2],parseInt(fdate[1],10)-1,fdate[0] );
```

parseInt() - она такая коварная!.. :)